# Фильтрация данных в Pandas DataFrame для комбинаций значений столбцов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame с `Columns = ['ball1', 'ball2', 'ball3', 'ball4', 'ball5', 'ball6', 'ball7']` заполненый целочисленными значениями (лотерейные шары).

Как можно оптимизровать ниже приведенный код для фильтрации данных? Текущее выражение фильтрует(оставляет) все лотерейные игры в которых три шара из семи, попадают под условие - значение следующего шара на единицу больше предыдущего. Например: [2,3,4,12,23,27,36] или [1,9,10,12,33,34,35]

```
m = draws[
            ((draws['ball1']+1 == draws['ball2']) & (draws['ball2']+1 == draws['ball3']))
            |
            ((draws['ball2']+1 == draws['ball3']) & (draws['ball3']+1 == draws['ball4']))
            |
            ((draws['ball3']+1 == draws['ball4']) & (draws['ball4']+1 == draws['ball5']))
            |
            ((draws['ball4']+1 == draws['ball5']) & (draws['ball5']+1 == draws['ball6']))
            |
            ((draws['ball5']+1 == draws['ball6']) & (draws['ball6']+1 == draws['ball7']))
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример исходного DF:

```
In [24]: draws
Out[24]:
   ball1  ball2  ball3  ball4  ball5  ball6  ball7
0     10     20     11      1      3     27     35
1      2      3      4     12     23     27     36
2      1      9     10     12     33     34     35
3      5     35     14     26     33     22     11
4      1      2     10     11     20     21     40
```

решение:

```
In [25]: mask = (draws.diff(axis=1) == 1).T.apply(lambda x: x*x.shift()).any()

In [26]: draws[mask]
Out[26]:
   ball1  ball2  ball3  ball4  ball5  ball6  ball7
1      2      3      4     12     23     27     36
2      1      9     10     12     33     34     35
```

погашово:

```
In [27]: draws.diff(axis=1)
Out[27]:
   ball1  ball2  ball3  ball4  ball5  ball6  ball7
0    NaN   10.0   -9.0  -10.0    2.0   24.0    8.0
1    NaN    1.0    1.0    8.0   11.0    4.0    9.0
2    NaN    8.0    1.0    2.0   21.0    1.0    1.0
3    NaN   30.0  -21.0   12.0    7.0  -11.0  -11.0
4    NaN    1.0    8.0    1.0    9.0    1.0   19.0

In [28]: draws.diff(axis=1) == 1
Out[28]:
   ball1  ball2  ball3  ball4  ball5  ball6  ball7
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False   True   True  False  False  False  False
2  False  False   True  False  False   True   True
3  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False   True  False   True  False   True  False

In [29]: (draws.diff(axis=1) == 1).T
Out[29]:
           0      1      2      3      4
ball1  False  False  False  False  False
ball2  False   True  False  False   True
ball3  False   True   True  False  False
ball4  False  False  False  False   True
ball5  False  False  False  False  False
ball6  False  False   True  False   True
ball7  False  False   True  False  False

In [30]: (draws.diff(axis=1) == 1).T.apply(lambda x: x*x.shift())
Out[30]:
         0    1    2    3    4
ball1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
ball2    0    0    0    0    0
ball3    0    1    0    0    0
ball4    0    0    0    0    0
ball5    0    0    0    0    0
ball6    0    0    0    0    0
ball7    0    0    1    0    0

In [31]: (draws.diff(axis=1) == 1).T.apply(lambda x: x*x.shift()).any()
Out[31]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: где и как ты устанавливаешь ограничения, чтобы выполнялось условие как минимум для трех шаров?

Comment: Для случая с 4 шарами я правильно модифицировал условие ? ->   (lambda x: x*x.shift(1)*x.shift(2))

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, а что показывают тесты? ;)

Comment: Я не за домашним компом. Мне главное суть понять как работает, а не слепо копировать.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, по идее все правильно - чтобы сказать точно нужно протестировать...

Comment: Один уточняющий вопрос по draws.diff(axis=1) . Если мне потребовалось бы использовать не diff, а мою пользовательскую функцию например  ball[X] % 3 = ball[x+1] %3, то как это сделать правильно ?

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, для этого можно воспользоваться `draws.shift(axis=1)`